# Sql server mandar correos "El servidor SMTP requiere una conexión segura o el cliente no se autenticó"

Tags: sql

Hola estoy tratando de mandar correos desde sql server pero me manda ese error.

```
El servidor SMTP requiere una conexión segura o el cliente no se autenticó
```

Ya desactive la seguridad de gmail
El password esta bien

El Imap tambien lo habilite

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
EXECUTE msdb.dbo.sysmail_add_profile_sp  
    @profile_name = 'FacturacionSAT',  
    @description = 'Perfil para mandar facturas a clientes.' ;  
GO

EXECUTE msdb.dbo.sysmail_add_principalprofile_sp  
    @profile_name = 'FacturacionSAT',  
    @principal_name = 'public',  
    @is_default = 1 ;
GO

EXECUTE msdb.dbo.sysmail_add_account_sp  
    @account_name = 'Gmail',  
    @description = 'Mandar facturas a clientes.',  
    @email_address = 'sf2georgedkcr@gmail.com',  
    @display_name = 'Automated Mailer',  
    @mailserver_name = 'smtp.gmail.com',
    @port = 587,
    @enable_ssl = 1,
    @username = 'sf2georgedkcr@gmail.com',
    @password = 'adsdasd' ;  
GO

EXECUTE msdb.dbo.sysmail_add_profileaccount_sp  
    @profile_name = 'FacturacionSAT',  
    @account_name = 'Gmail',  
    @sequence_number =1 ;  
GO

exec msdb.dbo.sysmail_configure_sp 'MaxFileSize','2000000'
exec msdb.dbo.sysmail_configure_sp 'AccountRetryAttempts','3'
exec msdb.dbo.sysmail_configure_sp 'DefaultAttachmentEncoding','MIME'

EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_send_dbmail
     @profile_name = 'FacturacionSAT',
     @recipients = 'georgedkcr@gmail.com',
     @body = 'The database mail configuration was completed successfully.',
     @subject = 'Automated Success Message';
GO
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Debes usar el `@use_default_credentials`. Por defecto Sql Server, usa sus propias credenciales. Cuando tienes `@use_default_credentials=1` te toma las credenciales del motor de base de datos, al contrario si agregas `@use_default_credentials=0` usará las credenciales de `@username` y `@password`.

Por otro lado debes tomar nota: si usas `SMTP` y usas `SSL` debes usar el puerto 465, que es un transporte seguro y si usas `TLS` debes usar el puerto `587` que es un transporte inseguro, pero que lo puedes actualizar para ser segura usando `STARTTLS`.